# Field collection item not visible to anonymous user

Tags: organic-groups

I have a field collection, 'related content', that displays inside the 'page' content type tpl. It is a 'field' in the page content type.  It  works perfectly fine while logged in as admin, but cannot be seen by the anonymous users.

UPDATE: I've actually determined that this has something to do with Organic Groups.  The 'page' that the field collection belongs to is a member of a group...the anonymous user can see this page, can see the body, title and other fields...however, I still cannot get the field collection to show up on the page even though the variables are available and can be dumped to the page...rendering the content using `render()` results in nothing, but works fine if logged in as admin.

If I simply do `var_dump($content['field_related_content'])` I can see that all of the information is there...however `print render($content['field_related_content'])` displays  nothing for anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions for the individual groups also have to be set for each added field...it was kind of buried and hard to find.  The path would be like `/group/node/13/admin/permissions`